# Inverse of complex metric

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

I have seen how to deduce that $g_{ik}g^{kj}=\delta_i{}^j$ for a real vector.
But when I try to develop an analogous argument for a complex vector space (something, that I am not sure is possible) I get into troubles. Let me elaborate my argument, so you can point me into the right direction.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with an hermitian positive definite inner product $V\times V\ni v,u \to v.u \in \mathbb{C}$. To be clear,

1. $v.v\geq 0$,
2. $v.v=0$ implies $v=0$,
3. $v.(u+cw)=v.w+c(v.w)$
4. $u.v=(v.u)^*$
   holds for all $v,u,w\in V$ and $c\in \mathbb{C}$ where $c^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $c$.

Let $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ and $\{b^1,...,b^n\}$ the corresponding dual basis of the dual space $V^*$, so $b^i(b_j)=\delta^i{}_j$.

Following Riesz theorem on the musical isomorphism, for an arbitrary $v\in V$, let $v{}^{\flat}\in V$ denote the element of $V^*$ such that $v{}^{\flat}(u)=b_i.u$ for all $u\in V$.
Similarly, for an arbitrary $f\in V^*$, let $f^{\sharp}$ denote the element of $V$ such that $f^{\sharp}.v=f(v)$ for all $v\in V$.
Let $f.g:=f^{\sharp}.g^{\sharp}$ denote the inner product between $f,g\in V^*$ induced by the inner product on $V$.

For any vector $v\in V$, let $v^*$ denote its complex conjugate.
In this way, $(cv)^*=c^*v^*$ for any $c\in \mathbb{C}$.
Let $g\in V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $g(v,u)=v^*.u$ for any $v,u\in V$.
With this definition, it can be easily seen that $g$ is bilinear and thus a tensor.
For instance,

\begin{eqnarray}
g(v+cw,u)
&=&
(v+cw)^*.u
\\
&=&
v^*.w+(cw)^*.u
\\
&=&v^*.w+(c^*w^*).u
\\
&=&
v^*.w+c^{**}(w^*.u)
\\
&=&
g(v,w)+cg(w,u)
\end{eqnarray}

$$
$$

Let $g_{ij}:=g(b_i{}^*,b_j)=b_i.b_j=(b_j.b_i)^*=g(b_j{}^*,b_i)=g_{ji}{}^*$.
Analogously, let $g^{ij}:=g(b^{i*},b^j)=...=g^{ji*}$.
With this in mind, we get
$$
b_i{}^{\flat}(b_j)=b_i.b_j=g(b_i{}^*,b_j)=g_{ij}
$$
and, therefore, $b_i{}^{\flat}=g_{ij}b^j$.

Now, we proceed to find the "inverse" of $g$ following an argument similar to the one used in the real case.
Namely,
\begin{eqnarray}
g_{ij}
&=&
g(b_i{}^*,b_j)
\\
&=&
b_i.b_j
\\
&=&
b_i{}^{\flat}.b_j{}^{\flat}
\\
&=&
(g_{ir}b^r).(g_{js}b^s)
\\
&=&
g_{ir}{}^*g_{js}(b^r.b^s)
\\
&=&
g_{ir}{}^*g_{js}g(b^{r*},b^s)
\\
&=&
g_{ir}{}^*g_{js}g^{rs}
\\
&=&
g_{ir}{}^*g^{rs}g_{sj}{}^*
\end{eqnarray}
At this point, I got stuck.
I can assume that $g^{rs}g_{sj}{}^*=\delta^r{}_j$ and conclude that
$$
g_{ij}=g_{ir}{}^*g^{rs}g_{sj}{}^*=g_{ir}{}^*\delta^r{}_j=g_{ij}{}^*
$$
implying that $g_{ij}$ is real, something I don't know if it makes sense.
Moreover, to make sense of the formulas, I have assumed what I was supposed to derive.
Am I doing something wrong? Does it make sense to have an inverse for $g$ in a manner analogous to the real case?

EDIT 1: Fixed a typo.

EDIT 2: Fixed a couple of typos.

EDIT 3: Fixed another typo.

EDIT 4: Improved text.

Comment: Haven't read your calculations in detail, but one point of suspicion is the "conjugation" map, which requires more structure than a complex vector space and an Hermitian pairing. (One can fix a real subspace $V_{\mathbf{R}}$ of $V$ whose complexification is $V$, and define conjugation with respect to $V_{\mathbf{R}}$ to act as the identity on $V_{\mathbf{R}}$ and as minus the identity on $iV_{\mathbf{R}}$. But that's extra structure _even in dimension_ $1$(!!).)